# SVN import trying to upload a non existent file

Tags: svn, version-control

I am trying to `import` a project into a remote svn repo.

However I get some errors:

```
svn: E175012: Connection timed out
svn: E000002: Additional errors:
svn: E000002: Can't open file '/export/server/subversion/spider/db/transactions/2-8.txn/props': No such file or directory
```

Why is svn trying to access a folder that doesn't exist in the original project?

Comment: It's not trying to import a file that isn't there. The server (assuming you're running a proper Subversion server) is trying to write to a path that it can't access (perhaps because it doesn't exist, perhaps due to permissions).

Comment: actually the server isn't in my control. So this error is on the server side and i should contact the administrator ?

Comment: Yes, you need to talk to your server administrator.